# Iterating through an array (Project Euler #23)

Tags: ruby, arrays, iteration

I have the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
c = 1
d = Array.new(6965)  #6965 is the amount of abundant numbers below 28123 of which all numbers greater than that can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers
f = 0
while c < 28124      # no need to go beyond 28123 for this problem
  a = 0
  b = 1
  i = true           # this will be set to false if a number can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers
  while b <= c/2 + 1 # checks will go until they reach just over half of a number
    if c % b == 0    # checks for integer divisors
      a += b         # sums integer divisors
    end
    b += 1           # iterates to check for new divisor
  end
  if a > c           # checks to see if sum of divisors is greater than the original number
    d << c           # if true it is read into an array
  end
  d.each{|j|         # iterates through array
    d.each{|k|       # iterates through iterations to check all possible sums for number
                     # false is declared if a match is found. does ruby have and exit statement i could use here?
      i = false if c - j - k == 0
    }
  }
  c+=1               # number that we are checking is increased by one
                     # if a number cannot be found as the sum of two abundant number it is summed into f
  f += c if i == true
end
puts f
```

For the following code, whenever I try to do a double iteration for my `d` array, I come up with the following errors:

> euler23:21:in `-': nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
>
>         from euler23:21:in`block (2 levels) in '
>         from euler23:20:in `each'
>
>         from euler23:20:in`block in '
>         from euler23:19:in `each'
>
>         from euler23:19:in`'

As I'm not familiar with Ruby, my various attempts at resolving this have been for naught. I get the feeling that there are some libraries I need to include, but my research hasn't mentioned any libraries, and I am at a loss. This code is meant to sum all the numbers that cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers; it is the [twenty third question from Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=23).

Comment: could you say the algorithm, what task it would perform. please mention that in your post. so that we can give you better solution.

Comment: I am so tempted to just copy the answer I have for that problem... :/

Comment: the algorithm is to find all the abundant numbers under 28123 and put them in an array, as  it's doing that it accesses the array and checks to see if a number can be made from the sum of any two of the abundant numbers i have found so far, if they cannot they get summed into a total

Comment: I've added a link to Project Euler problem #23 in addition to cleaning up the formatting and grammar.

Comment: Once you get an answer to make this work, you may pay a visit to http://codereview.stackexchange.com, that's not how you should be writing code, at least not in Ruby.

Comment: Isn't somewhat anti- the spirit of Project Euler to publish the full code of a solution to one of the problems? Nothing wrong with this question per-se, is there any way it could be boiled down to the OP's problem (in Ruby coding) without being a spoiler for others?

Comment: @NeilSlater ...assuming that this is both a correct and efficient solution. :)

Comment: @tokland how should one be writing ruby? i'm not sure because i come from a backround of c++ and am being required to learn ruby and most of it being unfamiliar to my i just kind of try to feel my way around in the dark

Comment: Don't worry about it, one of the core tenets of Ruby is that You're Always Doing It Wrong.

Comment: @joeframbach: that's what I think when I look at code I wrote 10 days before :-) elder: in higher-level languages (like Ruby) you usually focus more on expressions (maths) and not on statements (instructions). Add some abstraction and modularitzation (functions/methods) to the mix and you're done. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do this:

```
d = Array.new(6965)
```

you create an array of 6965 `nil` values.

If before line 21 you add this test code:

```
p [c,j,k]
```

then you get the result:

```
[1, nil, nil]
```

which shows that `j` and `k` are both `nil` values. You are iterating through empty items in your array.

If you change your creation of `d` to just:

```
d = [] # an empty array, which in Ruby can change size whenever you want
```

...then your code runs. (I've not let it run long enough to see if it runs *correctly*, but it runs without error for quite some time at least.)

---

Finally, a few bits of random style advice:

This code:

```
while b <= c/2 + 1
  if c % b == 0
    a += b
  end
  b += 1
end
```

can be rewritten more concisely and more Ruby-esque as:

```
b.upto(c/2+1){ a+=b if c%b==0 }
```

Similarly, this loop:

```
c=1
while c < 28124
  # ...
  c += 1
end
```

can be rewritten as:

```
1.upto(28123) do |c|
  # ...
end
```

When you ask about breaking out of a loop, you can use [`break` or `next`](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/tut_expressions.html#breakredoandnext) as appropriate, or [`throw` and `catch`](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/tut_exceptions.html#catchandthrow)—which is NOT used for error handling in Ruby— to jump to a particular nested loop level.

Comment: thank you, i have fixed the error and i'm running it right now for a result, but no errors so far

Comment: Note that (as you may know) many Project Euler problems are crafted in such a way that the simplest, brute-force computation of the answer may not finish in a timely fashion. (Goodness knows I've left many Euler programs running overnight, hoping for the simple solution to work.) I'm not sure if your code is of the brute-force variety, but if it takes more than a couple minutes in Ruby, there's probably a more elegant way to solve the problem.

Comment: yeah, my general idea is always to get a code to work, then once i get it working i refine and make it more efficient

Comment: so i have ran my code half a dozen times with your edit and i'm not sure why but it does really well until c = 2240 and f = 669038 and then it freezes

Answer (score 3):

The code below is faulty:

```
d.each{|j|                     
d.each{ |k|             
p c,j,k  #1,nil,nil
i = false if c - j - k == 0 }}
```

Because of:

```
1 - nil - nil
#TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
#      from (irb):2:in `-'
#      from (irb):2
#     from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```